# Determining if two values are equal, without using comparison operators (==, <=, >=, <, >)

Tags: python

So my assignment is to write a function in Python which takes in two integers, and will return true or false, depending on if the numbers are equivalent. I'm not allowed to use comparison operators.

I know I'm supposed to do something with the xor gate, because when you xor two binary numbers that are equal, you get all zeros.

```
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
-------
0 0 0 0
```

I don't know how to go about this in python. If anyone can give me some hints, or point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: If you subtract a number from itself you get 0 too. xor is just one way to do it. The xor operator in Python is named `^`, by the way (e.g .`a ^ b`).

Comment: In programming languages, you don't have gates, you have operators. In Python, the XOR operator is `^` https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: . . . does `not bool(a - b)` count? :P

Comment: Have you tried researching before asking? Otherwise the question comes across as "please do my assignment for me"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

```
# Using xor:
not bool(a ^ b)

# Simple substraction:
not bool(a - b)
```

Comment: The `cmp` function is way more intuitive, see below.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: It is, but `cmp()` is a comparison operator which is not allowed.

Comment: It's a function not an operator.

Comment: So is `operator.eq` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.eq), but that's most likely not the point of the exercise here.

Comment: I think this answer is probably the closest to the intent of the assignment.

Comment: Also note you don't need to call `bool()` since you're using `not`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in being a smart-ass:

```
def isEqual(num1, num2):
    a = {}
    a[num1] = 1
    try:
        a[num2]
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

Comment: Or `isEqual = lambda num1, num2: num2 in {num1}`

Comment: on reflection—same idea simplified: 

`{num1: 1}.get(num2, False)`